# Align the last-child li item to the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to float the last-child item to the right using `float:right` but it's not happening. Could someone help?

The CSS seems to be loading as it should but because of the flex being used in bootstrap 4, it is creating problem and not getting the desired result.

JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jbthz8L3/

```
<div id="main-nav" class="justify-content-end">
  <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="menu-item current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home active nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Main Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children dropdown nav-item"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link">Main Menu 2</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children dropdown nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Menu 1</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li class="menu-item nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Sub Menu 6</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children dropdown nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Menu 2</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li class="menu-item nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Sub Menu 11</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Sub Menu 12</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Sub Menu 13</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Sub Menu 14</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Sub Menu 15</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Sub Menu 16</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Sub Menu 17</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Menu 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Main Menu 3</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Main Menu 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-nav {
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
}
.navbar-nav > li:last-child {
   float: right;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
  margin: 0 15px;
}
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-toggle::after {
  border-bottom: 0.3em solid transparent;
  border-left: 0.3em solid;
  border-top: 0.3em solid transparent;
}
.dropdown-menu.show {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.dropdown.menu-item-has-children .dropdown.menu-item-has-children {
    position: unset;
}
.dropdown.menu-item-has-children .dropdown.menu-item-has-children>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
.dropdown.menu-item-has-children .dropdown.menu-item-has-children:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown.menu-item-has-children .dropdown.menu-item-has-children>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown.menu-item-has-children .dropdown.menu-item-has-children:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown.menu-item-has-children .dropdown.menu-item-has-children.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown.menu-item-has-children .dropdown.menu-item-has-children.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

Comment: How's this a duplicate of that question? It's very different.

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate of that question, as you can try to just add `ml-auto` which means `margin-left: auto;` to your class which contains *Main Menu 4*.

Comment: `margin-left: auto;` doesn't work. Try it and see for yourself.

Comment: Tried and tested in your code itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `float: right;` to

```
right: 0;
position: absolute;
```

Comment: Awesome! Got this working. Thank you so much! I'll accept the answer in 3 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Change `float:right;` with `margin-left:auto;`.

Answer (score 2):

Change the float:right to margin-left: auto;

Comment: Thanks. I got it working with Max's solution. Somehow this isn't working.

Comment: @Icewine Dhaval Jardosh had the same answer before you, so I would delete your answer.

Comment: Margin left auto works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/6rc1fxbL/

Answer (score 1):

One of the options:

```
right: 0;
position: absolute;
```

Maybe there are some pre-defined bootstrap-specific classes to solve it in a different way.